# Javascript Objects in browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How many objects is too many to process in javascript?

I've got a mapping application (google maps api) that has a 100,000 lat/long markers (with names). It's really simple data, but I it bogs down the page loading it.

Are there ways to deal with this? I'm not sure if the problem is that I'm loading too many objects, or if I just need to store/access the data in a less intensive way.

Comment: Do you have any code snippets?

Comment: 100,000 is probably too many.  Look at using a tile based renderer (KmlLayer and FusionTablesLayer are build in solutions that may work for you, but 100,000 is close to the limit for them as well).

Comment: [Too Many Markers!](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) (article in the documentation)

Answer (score 2):

I verify every day that 100,000 polygons with a significant number of coordinates (30 to 500 lat / lng each) involve a general slowing down of the duration of 3 to 5 seconds with a machine of discrete performance. You can make it more reactive the application suddvidento the population with a series of calls ajax portions sorted data .. This is often not easy from the point of view of application, but if it is possible allows a net improvement of performance even thanks to the asynchronous management of population data rendering them on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to know what's going wrong is to profile the CPU and the memory. It could just be too much data adding up, given it's 100,000 objects. Even with only a few properties on each, it adds up.

It's also possible that it just has trouble rendering that many points on the map. Depending on the business logic of your application, you can add something like a search or default filters to reduce the number needing to show.